# Get Node value from a XML using xmllint

Tags: xmllint

I have a xml called Det.xml like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <S:Body>
            <ns4:grtHgetRed xmlns:ns2="http://object" xmlns:ns3="http://object" xmlns:ns4="http://object">
                <RequestId>lol</RequestId>
                <MessageDateTime>54.009</MessageDateTime>
                <SenderId>UH</SenderId>
                <ReceiverId>GER</ReceiverId>
                <TrackingNumber>45</TrackingNumber>
                <ServerName>trewds</ServerName>
                <ResponseType>success</ResponseType>
                <StatusInfo>
                <Status>success</Status>
                <SystemMessage>Hagert</SystemMessage>
                <UserMessage>Hgert</UserMessage>
                <Origination>htref</Origination>
                </StatusInfo>
            </ns4:grtHgetRed>
        </S:Body>
    </S:Envelope>
```

I am trying to get the `ResponseType` node value `success` from it using `xmllint` in Unix shell script and so i tried the following :

```
echo "cat //*[local-name()='S:Envelope'/*[local-name()='S:Body']/*[local-name()='ns4:grtHgetRed']/*[local-name()='ResponseType']" | xmllint --shell Det
.xml | sed '/^\/ >/d' | sed 's/<[^>]*.//g'
```

But it's not working . Also i don't  have `xpath` in my unix environment . Can any one tell me what am i doing wrong here ?

I also tried using `statusMSG=="$(echo "cat /Envelope/Body/grtHgetRed/ResponseType/text()" | xmllint --nocdata --shell response.xml | sed '1d;$d')"`, then `echo "$statusMSG"`, but this gives an empty echo. Is this  because of namespace problem ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your `Det.xml` is always going to look like that (e.g. won't have any extra `ResponseType` nodes), you can simply use this:

```
xmllint --xpath 'string(//ResponseType)' Det.xml
```

And it will spit out: `success`

---

If your xmllint doesn't have xpath for some reason, you can always fall back to regular expressions for this sort of thing:

```
grep -Po '(?<=<ResponseType>)\w+(?=</ResponseType>)' Det.xml
```

It uses Perl regular expressions to allow for the positive look aheads / look behinds and only shows the matched part (not the whole line). This will output the same as above without using xmllint / xpath at all.

Comment: As I mentioned, i don't have `xpath`  in the unix env .

Comment: Ah, I wasn't quite sure what you were referring to. I thought it was a standalone script that you didn't have or something. I assume you have grep? I'll update my answer with an alternative.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight I've posted a solution using only grep. It's crude, but it gets the job done. If you're looking for a pure xmllint solution I'll let someone else venture there. Best of luck.

Comment: Perfect , thanks a lot. That's what i wanted . Up voted  and accepted .

Comment: Is it possible to stop xmllint --xpath from turning `ø` into `&#xF8;` etc. in id attributes?

Answer (score 1):

As you were looking for a solution using `xmllint` without `--xmlpath` Option, the following works for me:

```
echo "cat //ResponseType/text()" | xmllint --nocdata --shell /tmp/Det.xml | grep -v '/'
success
```

Your example `statusMSG=="$(echo "cat /Envelope/Body/grtHgetRed/ResponseType/text()" | xmllint --nocdata --shell response.xml | sed '1d;$d')"` does not work because you use the `echo "cat .../text()"` inside quotes without Quotation and you use the == Operator instead of an assignment.